# Ubuntu (mate) notifications

Tags: 22.04

I like the notification feature on my Ubuntu Mate 22.04 but it annoys me, that it shows firefox notifications, but once the big pop-ups go away there is no way to open these links from the bell icon. Is there a way to enable that feature so I could also open the webpages that sent the notification?